# Adding up datetime.datetime that are in single list

Tags: python, list, datetime, python-3.6, nested-lists

I've looked everywhere and I can't seem to find what I need. I have a list that contains datetime that I need to combine to find the sum. This list is parsed from a file and can have any number of datetime items in it. It looks like such for an example.

```
[datetime.datetime(1900, 1, 1, 1, 19, 42, 89000), datetime.datetime(1900, 1, 1, 2, 8, 4, 396000), datetime.datetime(1900, 1, 1, 0, 43, 54, 883000), datetime.datetime(1900, 1, 1, 0, 9, 13, 343000)]
```

The code I'm using to get this is this

```
time = [i[8] for i in smaller_list]
    try:
        times = [datetime.datetime.strptime(x, "%H:%M:%S.%f") for x in time]
    except ValueError:
        times = [datetime.datetime.strptime(x, "%M:%S.%f") for x in time]
```

Time gets the varibles from a larger nested list that I created to separate lines of data. I've tried datetime.datetime.combine() but I'm not really sure how to use this for items in a single list. Do I need to create a nested list of datetimes and sum them up? How do I iterate though this list and combine all the times for a sum? If I do have to create a nested list, how do I iterate through it to add up the times? Trying to wrap my head around this.

When you print time this is what is returned so the example list directly helps me.

```
[datetime.datetime(1900, 1, 1, 1, 19, 42, 89000), datetime.datetime(1900, 1, 1, 2, 8, 4, 396000), datetime.datetime(1900, 1, 1, 0, 43, 54, 883000), datetime.datetime(1900, 1, 1, 0, 9, 13, 343000)]
```

This is what the original times look like. I need to add up times such as these for total time. Usually in minutes with micro seconds included and rarely hours.

25:21.442

09:52.149

28:03.604

27:12.113

Comment: What _should_ the sum of your datetimes look like? Just adding up the years and months and stuff would put you around 7300 AD. Is that what you want?

Comment: Could you explain the logic behind the sum you want to perform?

Comment: @Kevin I updated the question. Usually just minutes down to the microseconds and sometimes hours

Comment: Why are you using datetimes for that, then, rather than timedeltas?

Comment: @ChihebNexus Updated the question. I just need minutes down to the micro second totaled and sometimes hours.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I'm new to coding so I didn't know anything about timedeltas

Comment: Then I suggest you read https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#timedelta-objects, it's likely to be a far better fit for your task. This isn't a coding thing, the difference between a point in time (`datetime`, `date`) and a duration (`timedelta`) is more general.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone else runs into this problem here is the code I used.

```
time = [i[8] for i in smaller_list]
sumtime = datetime.timedelta()
for i in time:
    try:
        (h, m, s) = i.split(':')
        d = datetime.timedelta(hours=int(h), minutes=int(m), seconds=float(s))
    except ValueError:
        (m, s) = i.split(':')
        d = datetime.timedelta(minutes=int(m), seconds=float(s))
    sumtime += d
print(str(sumtime))
```

If you're learning python it's pretty confusing trying to wrap your mind around date time and time delta. For duration's you need to use timedelta. You have to split the values up and pass the correct values to time delta and then you can sum them up to find the duration. Hopefully this helps someone out there.

If you need to round the microseconds to seconds you can use this code in place of d.

```
 d = datetime.timedelta(minutes=int(m), seconds=round(float(s)))
```